# MySQL greater than or equal to operator is ignoring its or equal to obligation

Tags: mysql, operators

If a price in a row is `38.03`, then the following search restrictions should all return the row containg the result.

`WHERE price >= '38.02' AND price <= '38.03'` (This works)

`WHERE price >= '20' AND price <= '100'` (This works)

`WHERE price >= '38.03' AND price <= '38.03'` (This doesn't work)

`WHERE price >= '38.03' AND price <= '100'` (This doesn't work)

`WHERE price >= '38.03'` (This doesn't work)

`WHERE price <= '38.03'` (This works)

The price is stored as a float in the DB.

So basically, `<=` is working whereas `>=` is not. Is there a reason why that could be?

Comment: Why do you need to enclose the value in single quotes?

Comment: Isn't this a variation of the classical floating point comparison problem?... I forget the name...

Comment: It may be too late now, but prices (and money) should always be stored as DECIMAL type, never floats. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: @Pekka웃 So far as I know, it's just the "floating point problem," maybe with the word "precision" thrown in there somewhere.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

keep in mind that `float` is a flawed data type when it comes to precision. If you represent `12` as float, you will get `11.99999999999998` or something.

`'38.03'` can be converted to decimal, or other data type that is more precise (depending on RDBMS, I am being general here), and it will differ from the float value.

float is 32 bit, low precision. Double works a lot better, being 64 bit data type. Decimal data type in some systems are 128 bit numeric data types for storing very precise numeric values, and is usually used for denominating money.

And, skip the habit of comparing using the `=` operator, of `float` values. Floats are used for approximate and fast calculations, and only comparison with a range is acceptable for checking the value of a `float`. That's valid for basically every single system.

Comment: +1 Yeah, just use `DECIMAL` instead. MySQL is pretty good with those.

Comment: Even 128 bits won't help you express 0.1 exactly.  Money is best represented as whole and fractional parts as integers.

Comment: @duffymo, you are talking about a fixed point decimal. There are 2 types of decimal, and some RDBMS have the `money` data type, which is a fixed point decimal with 2-4 decimal places.

Comment: That of course, makes perfect sense now that you mention it. Why was I storing currency as a float and not a decimal? Sheer ignorance.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Alexander.  I'll have to look into it, because my concern about rounding is true for all binary representations of floating point numbers.  I'd still rather have the two integers for whole and fractional parts to ensure that rounding was done properly.  Banks tend to care a great deal about those kinds of things.

Comment: @duffymo, if I understand it correctly, fixed point decimals are exactly what you are saying - 2 integers. But look into it still, banks are something I haven't worked with yet, I only make statistics :).

Comment: > keep in mind that float is a flawed data type when it comes to precision. 
> If you represent 12 as float, you will get 11.99999999999998 or something.

Comment: Totally agree that there may be a difference between the external representation and the bits stored on disk.
BUT I would assume that the conversion from External String to the internal bits would be done every time the same.
So it should be possible to do:

  INSERT IN table (id, price) VALUES (1, 38.03)

  SELECT * FROM table WHERE price = 38.03

The String "38.03" from SELECT should be converted into the same bitpattern as INSERT, so finding the record

Answer (score -1):

When you use quotes (') your variables will be treated as strings. I think thats your problem.

Try: WHERE price >= 38.03 AND price <= 38.03

Comment: Try it yourself and you will notice that there is no difference. :)

Comment: Given query above equals to WHERE price = 38.03

Comment: mysql> SELECT  38.03 <= 38.03;
result: 1
mysql> SELECT  38.03 < 38.03;
result: 0

Comment: likewise, mysql> SELECT 38.03 <= '38.03'; result: 1 mysql> SELECT 38.03 < '38.03'; result: 0