# Incorrect count when using comparison operator

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison-operators

i have 39 records in one table with the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table` WHERE `status` = 1
```

Now i want the result count when the certain maximum decimal value is X

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `price` <= 247504.91
```

In this particular case **247504.91** is the maximum price value for that table

The first query returns 39 but the second returns 38, seems it's excluding the last record or i'm not sure, but i'm kinda stuck at the moment in why is it happening? what am i doing wrong?.

**EDIT**

The datatype of the price field is Decimal

[image]

Comment: Is one of the records price value null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL greater than or equal to operator is ignoring its or equal to obligation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667161/mysql-greater-than-or-equal-to-operator-is-ignoring-its-or-equal-to-obligation)

Comment: @Andrew None of them is null or empty

Comment: @Vulcronos i already saw that answer and look for it doesn't apply to my situation

Comment: You should use DECIMAL for your price column and read the question linked by @Vulcronos

Comment: @DannyG: Why does it not apply to your question?

Comment: Run `select id from table where status = 1 and id not in (select id from table where status = 1 and price <= 247504.91)` and go look at the id that this returns. And tell us the status and price.

Comment: @VMai how about reading my answer to his answer? i never stated that i'm using a float

Comment: @DannyG Just because you are using a decimal instead of a float doesn't mean the question doesn't apply.  Please verify that the row that is not returned is the 247504.91 row.  If so, change 247504.91 in the where clause to 247504.92 and see if that returns all 39

Comment: @Vulcronos Well, none of the answers helps me with my issue.

Comment: @DannyG Please check, which row is missing: SELECT t.id FROM `table` t WHERE t.status = 1 AND t.id NOT IN (SELECT t1.id FROM `table` t1 WHERE t1.status = 1 AND t1.price <= 247504.91) should do it. You can use a left join too. I can't reproduce the behaviour you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your price values is NULL arithmetic operators won't work on them, so they will not be considered in the total record count. Use the following query to put in a value of 0 for each price that is null

```
UPDATE `table` SET `price` = 0 WHERE `price` IS NULL
```

### Avoid Hardcoded Values

Also, for writing querys like this you should have a nested query fetch the max value of the column instead of using a hardcoded number. This way if the max changes you do not have to go back and update the query, plus it will not be prone to human error (inputting the wrong number).

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `price` <= 
(SELECT MAX(`price`) FROM `table` WHERE `status` = 1)
```

Comment: Price can't be null or empty or 0 since that validation is being made server side when that table gets populated.